# Is there any way to dynamically submit a post to Facebook with PHP/ Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, laravel-5.1

I am developing a web application that having a blogs section.

My client requirement is that he want to submit the blog post to facebook  after inserting to DB.

That means automatically needs to post in Facebook with web application.

My Doubts are,

Is there any possibilities in this ?

If Yes, How can we done with PHP ?

Thanks.

Comment: yes its possible. [start here](https://developers.facebook.com/)

Comment: You can use cron job to check your DB for new insertion so you can fire your facebook posting script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the facebook graph api.
At https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing you can read more about it.

Basicly, right before or after your db insert you should uae the api to post it to the facebookpage by sending POST request with proper parameters. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

You can use this to send these POST requests